# String Orientation and Level Structures

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, modular-forms, cobordism

Atiyah, Bott and Shapiro defined orientations of real and complex K-theory that were later refined to maps of ($E_\infty$-ring) spectra 
$$MSpin \to KO$$
and
$$MSpin^c \to KU.$$

Likewise, but more complicated, the Witten genus was refined in a [paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~mando/papers/koandtmf.pdf) by Ando, Hopkins and Rezk to the string orientation
$$MString \to tmf$$
into connective $tmf$. This has also a "complex" version: for every (even periodic) elliptic spectrum, there is an orientation
$$MU\langle 6\rangle \to E,$$
as already shown earlier in [Elliptic Spectra, the Witten Genus and the Theorem of the Cube](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/musix.pdf).

This provides "string orientations" for many variants of $TMF$ with level structure; for example, $TMF(n)$ is an elliptic spectrum for $n\geq 3$. But it does not constitute a fully satisfactory theory of string orientations for topological modular forms with level structures for the following two reasons:

1. It is not obvious that the map $MU\langle 6\rangle \to TMF(n)$ factor over its connective version $tmf(n)$. The latter is understood to be the connective cover of the "compactified" $Tmf(n)$ defined first by Goerss and Hopkins and then in greater generality by [Hill and Lawson](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7394).
2. Many level structures do *not* define elliptic spectra. For example, the spectra $TMF_0(n)$ are not complex oriented in general.

So my question is: Is there a notion of "string bordism with level structure" and corresponding string orientations, producing for example a map into $tmf_0(3)$?

Note: The composition $MString \to tmf \to tmf_0(3)$ is obviously not what I want.

Comment: tmf_0(2) should admit an $MSO$ orientation (the Ochanine genus). I'm trying to write this down, actually, as an exercise in understanding the Ando-Hopkins-Rezk stuff.

Comment: The paper "The Jacobi orientation and the two-variable elliptic genus" (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605554; by Ando, French and Ganter) is potentially relevant.

Comment: I believe the paper "[**HP$^2$**-bundles and elliptic homology](https://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/files/KreckStolzElliptic.pdf)" by Kreck and Stolz (Acta **171** (1993) pp. 231-261) should be mentioned too as highly relevant

Answer (score 10):

Dylan's nice paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05116 answers this question.

Answer (score 3):

For $tmf_0(3)$, there should exist an orientation from the bordism spectrum of manifolds with $BString(2)$-structure, where $BString(2)$ is the homotopy fiber of $p_1:BSpin\to K(Z,4)$. The composition with $MString\to MString(2)$ would however be the map you do not want.

Comment: What do you mean by "should"?